# Value of the previous period according to the filter

Tags: dax

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3UmR8.png)I want to create a measure that calculates the value of the "Objectif" measure of the previous period according to the date filter:
´

For example :
if filter on Year 2021 take the value of 2020
if filter on Qt4 2021 take the value of Qt 3 2021
if filter october 2021 take the value of september 2021
Automatically in dax?,

Comment: I think you need to read up on time intelligence. Your question is way too broad at this point.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use this DAX time intelligence function:

[SAMEPERIODLASTYEAR](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dax/sameperiodlastyear-function-dax)